# In a dataframe in pandas, how can I push the front column value of specific row to the back and fill it with '00' in its place?

Tags: python, numpy

```
data = {'1':['cd','aa','1a'],
        '2':['ab','1b'],
        '3':['1a']}
```

Wanted output:

```
data = {'1':['cd','aa','1a'],
        '2':['00','ab','1b'],
        '3':['00','00','1a]}
```

So I solved it as follows, but the problem is that it is too slow. Thank you for your reply

```
import pandas as pd

for i in (len(data)):
    print(i)
    count = 0
    if ((data['1'].isna())[i]==True):
      count = 3
    elif ((data['2'].isna())[i]==True):
      count = 2
    elif ((data['3'].isna())[i]==True):
      count = 1
    data.loc[i] = data.loc[i].shift(count, fill_value='00')
```

there are 8 columns for my case, this is an example

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should upvote the answers that help you and accept the best one. This is easily done by clicking on signs at left upper end of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data = {'1':['cd','aa','1a'],
        '2':['ab','1b'],
        '3':['1a']}

# FOR EACH ITEM, INSERT '00' AT FIRST POSITION    
# TILL LENGTH IS ADEQUATE:
for d in data:
    while len(data[d]) < 3: 
        data[d].insert(0, '00')

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'1': ['cd', 'aa', '1a'], '2': ['00', 'ab', '1b'], '3': ['00', '00', '1a']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) on your DataFrame to sort the values using the NA/not-NA property:

```
data = {'1':['cd','aa','1a'],
        '2':['ab','1b'],
        '3':['1a']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').T
idx = np.argsort(df.notna().to_numpy(), axis=0)

out = (pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()[idx, np.arange(df.shape[1])],
                    columns=df.columns,
                    index=df.index)
         .fillna('00')
      )
```

Or with pandas' `apply`, which is shorter but slower for large datasets:

```
out = (df
   .apply(lambda r: r.sort_values(key=pd.notna, ignore_index=True))
   .fillna('00')
 )
```

Output:

```
    1   2   3
0  cd  00  00
1  aa  ab  00
2  1a  1b  1a
```

*NB. If you want a dictionary as output:*

```
out.to_dict('list')
{'1': ['cd', 'aa', '1a'],
 '2': ['00', 'ab', '1b'],
 '3': ['00', '00', '1a']}
```